# error in installation moveit2 tutorial

Tags: moveit, colcon

i tried `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y` and `src/*/` , `src/*/* ..`

but Cmake can not find it.

So, i tried install it.(move_msgs pkg)

but it was already the newest version

````
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findmoveit_msgs.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "moveit_msgs", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "moveit_msgs" with
  any of the following names:

    moveit_msgsConfig.cmake
    moveit_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "moveit_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "moveit_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "moveit_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.

```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clone this into your workspace using the branch corresponding to your ROS distribution.

https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_msgs

Comment: Thank you for your interest, really.
I've run both versions you mentioned (Main and Humble)
And they all failed.
So I thought again about what the difference was from the existing installation.
Before, /opt/ros existed, but this time I installed ros and main was not installed in that path.
For some reason I made the change, so I used setup.bash installed in ros2_ws.
Then I encountered that error, and after thinking about it for a few hours, I looked up the path again and found /opt/ros/humble, and when I used the setup, there was no error.

Comment: Happy to hear it's working now! I guess this issue can be closed then.